# Power BI display items not viewed by a column of non related table

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have 3 tables : user, article, views

article table related to view table and views table related to user table.

I wanna to display list of article not viewed by user. The problem I am facing is the fact that my view table doesn't contain all articles only those viewed at least one time, and there isn't a direct relation between articles and users.

for example, I have 1000 articles,  and a user 1 check 5 articles , then total article viewed by user 1  is 5 and article not viewed by user 1 is (1000-5) which is 995.

Could you help me please to solve this problem

Comment: Please share some code for what you have tried.  You might be able to use `EXCEPT()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.